# Asp.net is not defined,$(...).dxButton is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

It gives the jquery error while using the devexpress table getting data from SQL. by this reason, it does not call the controller.

this is the picture of the problem[image]

```
        this is the bundle config
        // jQuery
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js",
                     "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"
                     ));
```

my _Layout.cshtml.[image]

Devexpress code:
`@{
        ViewBag.Title = "RoleGroup_Index";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        }`

```
<div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <h2>Static Tables</h2>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Dashboard_1", "Dashboards")">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>Rol  Group Tanımlama</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <strong>Rol Group Tanımlama</strong>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid()
     .ID("RoleGroupTable")
 .DataSource(d => d.WebApi().Controller("UserRoleManagementApi").Key("Get")

       .LoadAction("GetAllOrders")
        .InsertAction("InsertOrder")
        .UpdateAction("UpdateOrder")
        .DeleteAction("RemoveOrder"))
   .Columns(c =>
    {
    c.Add().DataField("RoleGroupId");
    c.Add().DataField("Name");
    c.Add().DataField("Description");
    c.Add().DataField("InsertionDate");
    c.Add().DataField("InsertedUserId");
    c.Add().DataField("UpdatedDate");
    c.Add().DataField("UpdatedUserId");
}

   .Paging(p => p.PageSize(4))
.FilterRow(f => f.Visible(true))
.HeaderFilter(f => f.Visible(true))
.GroupPanel(p => p.Visible(true))
.Grouping(g => g.AutoExpandAll(false))
.RemoteOperations(true)
  .NoDataText("No Data Found")
```

I even added a devexpress button at the end but it does not work.

Comment: I do not see where you add the bundled scripts to the webpage to be loaded

Comment: in the layout, as     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery");

Comment: open up the browser tools when loading the page.  Make sure in the network trace it is able to load the scripts

Comment: @KenTucker It loads the scripts, I have been handling this problem for 2 days but could not find a solution. Jquery works on other files such as showing a graph, however when it comes to devexpress, it simply does not work. Do you think is it a problem to load jquery twice. First, it loads at the login page. secondly in devexpress page.??

Comment: you should only load jquery once per page